# Как добавить к программе функцию нажатия клавиш ?

Tags: c++

Создал стек, а теперь хочу сделать следующее:

При нажатии на кнопку с буквой "А" он добавлял туда элемент a.add(), а при нажатии на "D" удалял оттуда элемент a.take() ... поможете с кодом?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class query
{
private:
int *qu;
int ladr,badr,size;

public:
query(int n){qu=new int[n];size=n;badr=0;ladr=0;}

void add(int x) { if(badr==size) badr=0; qu[badr++]=x; }
int take(){return qu[ladr++];}

void print(){for(int i=ladr;i!=badr;i++){if(i==size)i=0;cout<<qu[i]<<"";}cout<<endl;}

};

int main( )

{ query a(50);

a.add(23);a.add(1);a.add(-5);

cout<<a.take()<<endl;
cout<<a.take()<<endl;
a.print();

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В Windows вызывайте getch() в *nix смотрите в сторону termios.

Например можно написать такой свой "getch()"

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>

....

  struct termios oldt, newt;
  int   l, tty;
  char  buf[2];

....

    tty = open ("/dev/tty",O_RDWR);
    tcgetattr( tty, &oldt );
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    // Установим чтение терминала без ожидания и без ECHO
    tcsetattr( tty, TCSANOW, &newt );

....
    l = read(tty,buf,1);  // здесь читаем 1 байт без ожидания <ВК>
    // Если l == 0 то EOF
.....

    tcsetattr( tty, TCSANOW, &oldt );  // В конце работы восстановим режимы терминала
```

Comment: у меня windows, можно по-подробнее, а то я из твоего кода ничего не понял

Comment: Код для \*nix. До read() происходит инициализация "виндузовского" getch(), вместо getch() вызывается read(). В первом байте buf будет введенный символ. Это у Вас должно быть в цикле, анализируете buf[0] и вызываете add() или take() или, например, завершаете программу.

@userx в своем ответе уже написал пример кода для виндоуз. _getch() и getch() IMHO эквивалентны.

Comment: Вообще, по формулировке вопроса я решил, что Вам надо читать символы **без ожидания ввода** <Enter> (<ВК>). Отсюда и ответ про getch() и аналогичное чтение в \*nix.

Если это (без ожидания) не обязательно, то можете просто читать в цикле строки ввода вида:

    A NNN

ввод числа и выполните add с ним

    D

выполнить take

Comment: если дам тебе код, можешь мне помочь? там ошибку у меня выдает

Answer (score 2):

Для консоли под Windows

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    int ch;

    do
    {
        ch = _getch();

        if (ch == 'A')
            ; // TODO: add
        if (ch == 'D')
            ; // TODO: delete
    } while( ch != 'z' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую, надеюсь все будет ок, если что задамся вопросами )

Comment: вот я выложил код, можешь подсказать после чего его вставить и как будет при этом выглядеть твой код?